# How to solve "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, perl, sh

I'm trying to run a `sh` script and get the following error on Mac:

```
/usr/bin/perl^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Remove `^M` control chars with

```
perl -i -pe 'y|\r||d' script.pl
```

Comment: @Bharat it does in-place edit of file, where it removes every occurrence of `\r` control char (or `^M` as shell refers to it).

Answer (score 60):

> /usr/bin/perl^M:

Remove the `^M` at the end of `usr/bin/perl` from the `#!` line at the beginning of the script. That is a spurious ASCII 13 character that is making the shell go crazy.

Possibly you would need to inspect the file with a binary editor if you do not see the character.

You could do like this to convert the file to Mac line-ending format:

```
$ vi your_script.sh
```

once in vi type:

```
 :set ff=unix

 :x
```

Comment: "Making the interpreter go crazy" is not accurate. The error is coming from the kernel/loader because it considers the `\r` part of the filename and can't find that path. No interpreter is ever launching.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: thanks for the remark, completely on point! I edited my answer…

Comment: Cool. It works for me. I have created the perl file in Sublime (windows), then I have copied the file to the Unix and get the error : /usr/bin/perl^M: bad interpreter:   After this fix, everything is working good. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're trying to use DOS/Windows text format on Linux/Unix/OSX machine.

In DOS/Windows text files a line break, also known as newline, is a combination of two characters: a Carriage Return (CR) followed by a Line Feed (LF). In Unix text files a line break is a single character: the Line Feed (LF).

Dos2unix can convert for you the encoding of files, in example:

```
dos2unix yourfile yourfile
```

For help, run: `man dos2unix`.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have weird line endings in your script: `^M` is a carriage return `\r`. Transform your script to Unix line endings (just `\n` instead of `\r\n`, which is the line ending on Windows systems).

Comment: OS X is a Unix system. However, some tools (editors) may have been set to Windows line endings for interop. You also get bad line endings when you transfer files as binaries from a Windows computer. Did you write the script yourself or copy it from somewhere?

Comment: There you have it. Just open the file in your favourite editor and save it with Unix line endings (sergio shows how to do it with Vi(m)).

Answer (score 4):

And if you prefer Sublime Text - simply go to View -> Line Endings and check Unix.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/perl`echo -e '\r'`
```

Comment: I let one of the local cats read this answer and she recoiled, yowling, and then leapt 20ft directly up into the air to flee across a roof.  I also fear that, in the brief period that your answer was exposed to the open air of my city, that Lovecraftian horrors must've been permitted to enter it.  I'll tell you more after I can find and dissect the cat.