# sh: scripts/image_to_code.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: cocoapods

I'm running `pod install` for a project and am running into this error:

```
Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.21.1)
[!] /bin/bash 
set -e
find src -name \*.png | grep -v @ | grep -v '/tests/' | grep -v 'Tests/' | grep -v -- - | sed -e 's|\(.*\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).png|scripts/image_to_code.py -i \1/\2.png -c \2 -o src|' | sh && find src -name \*.wav | grep -v @ | grep -v -- - | sed -e 's|\(.*\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).wav|scripts/audio_to_code.py -i \1/\2.wav -c \2 -o src|' | sh

sh: scripts/image_to_code.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've seen fixes like this: [How to solve "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131249/how-to-solve-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory) but surely I don't have to modify pod source files before running pod install.

I've seen a fix here: 
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2418 that suggests doing:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python^M
```

which seems crazy.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Don't use a file created in WinDos. It is clear that it has never been tested in Unix. (Most likely it has never been tested.)

Answer (score 2):

Try converting `scripts/image_to_code.py` to UNIX line-end format, for example using `dos2unix` or any text editor, which can properly save file in DOS and UNIX formats.

Most likely reason of this problem is [some] script files were converted to DOS/Windows format (while extracting for example).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with the Ruby interpreter. The solution for me was to just re-run the cocoapods installer a la

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6778 lead me to trying this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading my Mac OS to Catalina. It turns out the gems didn't point to the correct version of Ruby after upgrade. So i did what this thread suggested: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15460

My steps where (in Terminal):

```
// Uninstall gems
sudo gem uninstall -aIx 

// Go to `gems` directory
cd ~/.gem

// Remove all contents
rm -r * 

// Install the gems again
gem install fastlane bundler cocoapods
```